# What are the supported Bluetooth profiles of Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm looking for an official documentation of what Bluetooth profiles are supported by which Android version.

Looking into the API docs I found the `BluetoothProfile` interface that only hints to A2DP, Gatt, Health and HFP. I know for sure that Android also supports SAP and MAP.

**Question:** Is there an official site that documents the supported profile profiles including version?

Comment: You can find android supported Bluetooth profiles here. https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services#bluetooth-profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services

> Over Bluetooth, devices can transmit data that can be used for interactive services such as audio, messaging, and telephony. The Bluetooth profiles used for different services can be found in include/hardware/bluetooth.h.

Comment: This hasn't been updated past Android version 8.0 for some reason

Comment: Does Android support SDAP?